# How to use parallel task in Ant

Tags: java, ant, parallel-processing

Hello im working on application which is runing tests one by one trough Ant call. In .bat file build.xml is called in which is called another file with name of .class test which are called is there any chance to make this parallel in Ant?

My ant config look like this:

```
<target name="testexec-run-pattern" description="=> run JUnit tests by Pattern">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.dir}/xml" />
    <input addproperty="input.pattern" />
    <echo message="Executing pattern: ${input.pattern}" />
    <junit showoutput="true" printsummary="on">
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
        <batchtest todir="${junit.dir}/xml">
            <formatter type="xml" extension=".xml" usefile="true" />
            <zipfileset src="${test.jar}">
                <patternset includes="${input.pattern}" />
            </zipfileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

where patternset includes are test to run. And i want these test to run parallel. I think i will need something like foreach for all tests to be run in thread.

Comment: I recommend using Jenkins to manage your build job execution, rather than ANT itself. For example something worth checking out if the parallel Test executor plugin: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/parallel-test-executor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ant, Task can be executed in parallel using `parallel` tag. Following is an example extracted from [official Apache Ant site](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html):

> <macrodef name="dbpurge">
>      <attribute file="file"/>
>     <sequential>
>        <java jar="utils/dbpurge.jar" fork="true" >
>          <arg file="@{file} />
>        </java>
>     </sequential>
>   </macrodef>
>
> <parallel threadCount="4">
>    <dbpurge file="db/one" />
>    <dbpurge file="db/two" />
>    <dbpurge file="db/three" />
>    <dbpurge file="db/four" />
>    <dbpurge file="db/five" />
>    <dbpurge file="db/six" />
>    <dbpurge file="db/seven" />
>    <dbpurge file="db/eight" />
>    <!-- repeated about 40 times -->
>   </parallel>
>
> This example represents a typical need for use of the threadCount and threadsPerProcessor attributes. Spinning up all 40 of those tasks could cripple the system for memory and CPU time. By limiting the number of concurrent executions you can reduce contention for CPU, memory and disk IO, and so actually finish faster. This is also a good candidate for use of threadCount (and possibly threadsPerProcessor) because each task is independent (every new JVM is forked) and has no dependencies on the other tasks.

Refer [official Apache Ant site](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html) for more information.